# Set writing mode / text direction bottom to top

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-transforms

I can't find a solution to make the green elements start at the bottom right of the container, like in right image ("Need").

Does CSS provide a way to align/orient elements from the bottom?

"Default" and "Need" element's location illustrated.

[image]

SNIPPET

```css
    .cnt {
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid green;
  text-align:center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.itm {
  transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1);
  display: inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  width:20px;
  margin:10px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  transition:transform 0.5s;
}
.itm:hover {
  transform: translate(0px, -3px) scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="cnt">
  <div class="itm">1</div>
  <div class="itm">2</div>
  <div class="itm">3</div>
  <div class="itm">4</div>
  <div class="itm">5</div>
  <div class="itm">6</div>
  <div class="itm">7</div>
  <div class="itm">8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does CSS provide a way to align/orient elements from the bottom?

Surprisingly, in horizontal writing mode, it doesn't appear so.

There are various properties, including `writing-mode`, `direction`, `text-orientation` and `flex-direction`, that allow you to re-arrange the flow of content.

But none of them appear to allow the laying out of content in a horizontal writing mode starting from the bottom right. Maybe somebody could correct me on this.

In the meanwhile, here's a hack (pure CSS):

```css
.cnt {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
.itm {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(0px, 0px) scaleY(-1) scaleX(1);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.itm:hover {
  transform: translate(0px, -3px) scaleY(-1.1) scaleX(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="cnt">
  <div class="itm">8</div>
  <div class="itm">7</div>
  <div class="itm">6</div>
  <div class="itm">5</div>
  <div class="itm">4</div>
  <div class="itm">3</div>
  <div class="itm">2</div>
  <div class="itm">1</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o7hr07k6/

Answer (score 1):

It's easy if you can reverse the order of the itms in the source.

```css
.cnt {
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid green;
  text-align:center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  transform:rotate(180deg);
}

.itm {
  display: inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  width:20px;
  margin:10px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  transform:rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="cnt">
  <div class="itm">8</div>
  <div class="itm">7</div>
  <div class="itm">6</div>
  <div class="itm">5</div>
  <div class="itm">4</div>
  <div class="itm">3</div>
  <div class="itm">2</div>
  <div class="itm">1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Transform rotate can't use cause already used for scale and transition. It will rotate block instead or together with scale and transition

Comment: @Dmitry Then you should post a more complete example of your existing CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly it, but it's the closest I could get with a pure CSS solution.  It's pretty ugly, though.  Posting more so that others may see it and use it to get to the correct answer.

```css
.cnt {
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid green;
  text-align:center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: flex-end;
}

.itm {
  transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1);
  display: inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  width:20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin:10px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  transition:transform 0.5s;
}

.itm:hover {
  transform: translate(0px, -3px) scale(1.1);
}


.itm:nth-child(1) {
  order: 8;
}


.itm:nth-child(2) {
  order: 7;
}


.itm:nth-child(3) {
  order: 6;
}


.itm:nth-child(4) {
  order: 5;
}


.itm:nth-child(5) {
  order: 4;
}


.itm:nth-child(6) {
  order: 3;
}


.itm:nth-child(7) {
  order: 2;
}


.itm:nth-child(8) {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="cnt">
  <div class="itm">1</div>
  <div class="itm">2</div>
  <div class="itm">3</div>
  <div class="itm">4</div>
  <div class="itm">5</div>
  <div class="itm">6</div>
  <div class="itm">7</div>
  <div class="itm">8</div>
</div>
```